# Which ubuntu version compatible with my netbook

Tags: dual-boot

I'd like to have ubuntu as my dual boot os alongside with win 10. I've tried 16.04.1 lts in this pc but not satisfied with the performance.  Need suggestion which version is good for my performance also in graphic term. My pc spec are all basic except my ram is now have upgrade to 2gb. Thanks in advance. -hp mini 110-3000-

Answer (score 1):

I use Lubuntu 16.04 on a Mini 110c-1100.  It has adequate performance, which considering that it has an Intel Atom N270, is not unexpected.  I am able to run Netflix and Skype satisfactorily.  Some applications like Google Hangouts video chat do not work well.

Comment: As for now i think win 10 run smoother than this ubuntu version including startup and shutdown. Should i downgrade to your version?